# How to set a custom font-size from my c# controller

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, razor

I m building a web application using Asp.net c#. So from my controller, I want to set the font-size of the buttons in the page. So I'm build this code:

```
@foreach (var x in @ViewBag.paginaIniziale.pulsanti)
    {
        if (@x.idTipoPulsante == 4)
        {
            <button type="button" class="buttonHomeQuestionario" style="background:@x.backgroundColor;font-size:@x.fontSize;" onclick="location.href='@Url.Action("iniziaQuestionario", "Home")'">@x.etichetta</button>
        }
        else if (@x.idTipoPulsante == 5)
        {
            <button type="button" class="buttonHomeQuestionario" style="background:@x.backgroundColor;font-size:@x.fontSize;" onclick="location.href='@Url.Action("riprendiQuestionario", "Home")'">@x.etichetta</button>
        }
    }
```

If if try to start this code, on the web page I have this situation:

```
<button type="button" class="buttonHomeQuestionario" style="background:#000123;font-size:20;"/>
```

to ensure that the fontsize settings are correctly interpreted by the browser, the string 'px' should also be set after the number 20. How can I solve?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you already said you need to add `px`, while avoiding to confuse Razor. You can do this using parenthesis around the `x.fontSize` part, which will make it clear to Razor where the C# expression starts and ends:

```
<button type="button" class="buttonHomeQuestionario"
    style="background:@x.backgroundColor;font-size:@(x.fontSize)px;" 
    onclick="location.href='@Url.Action("iniziaQuestionario", "Home")'">@x.etichetta</button>
```